# Change element ID onmouseover/onmouseout any element in a class

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

I need to change an element's id when I mouseover a different element in a particular class.  I then want to change the element id back to what it was previously on mouseout from the same element that I moused over before.

In the code below I propound a basic HTML code to clarify my question.  I wish to change `<div id="Set1">` to `<div id="Set2">` onmouseover of any `<div class="tomouseover">`.  Onmouseout from that same element I wish to change the original element's id back to `<div id="Set1">`.

```
<div id="Set1">Div to change id</div>
<div class="tomouseover">Mouse over to change Set1 to Set2</div>
<div class="tomouseover">Mouse over to change Set1 to Set2</div>
```

+1 to ANY ideas!  I'm royally stuck...

Comment: I prefer not.  This is in a Google Gadget.  I could if I had to though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Derek's answer but you will soon discover that *querySelector* is not supported by IE8 in quirks mode or IE 7 and lower, and that *addEventListener* is not supprted by IE 8 and lower at all.

Choices for plain js include writing your own *getElementsByClassname* function (not particularly difficult) or use event delegation so that you attach only one listener for each event and need a simple *hasClass* function.

Anyhow, here's an example:

Some standard library functions that any javscripter should have in a library or be able to code in a few minutes:

```
// Minimalist addEvent function, ok for the current web
function addEvent(el, fn, evt) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(evt, fn, false) 
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn);
  } 
}

// Returns true or false depending on whether element el has class classname
function hasClassname(el, classname) {
  var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + classname + '(\\s|$)');
  return re.test(el.className); 
}
```

A function to do the work:

```
// Toggle the id. Note that this deals with the case where
// the element to toggle isn't found to prevent errors being thrown
function toggleId(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var o;

  if (hasClassname(el, 'tomouseover')) {

    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
      o = document.getElementById('set1');

      if (o) o.id = 'set2';

    } else if (e.type == 'mouseout') {
      o = document.getElementById('set2');

      if (o) o.id = 'set1';
    }
  }
}

// Attach the listener onload, could also add from a bottom
// script or inline. If inline, use `toggleId(event)`
window.onload = function() {
  addEvent(document.body, toggleId, 'mouseover');
  addEvent(document.body, toggleId, 'mouseout');
}
```

The above will work in all browsers back to IE6 and NN 3 or so and will continue to work in future browsers that are either W3C or IE event models.

Comment: Wow.  That's overboard for my code, but I'll give it a shot!  Thanks for pointing this out--I hadn't noticed...

Comment: FYI, YouTube does not support IE 8 too.

Comment: @Derek - Literally Side-popping...  I realize your reputation is 8901-10 below RobG.  I prefer that my things work in IE8- too, the version many lame gadget users still use.  Loyalty next time :)

Comment: The `addEvent` and `hasClassname` functions are something you write once and add to your library. Bundle with a "namespace" object to keep things neat. Then you are just writing the logic, which you need to do regardless of which library you use (yours or anyone elses). As for IE 8 support, +50% of IE users are on 8 or lower. The web is about inclusion and the broadest possible reach (within reason). It was that ethods that stopped IE from dominating the web. However, developers that exclude IE by writing incompatible code are not only lazy, but against the ethos that made the web what it is.

Answer (score 3):

Pure JavaScript: (credit goes to Nathan's answer)

```
var ele = document.querySelectorAll(".tomouseover");
for(var i=0; i < ele.length; i++){
    ele[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        document.querySelector("#Set1").setAttribute("id", "Set2");
    });
    ele[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
        document.querySelector("#Set2").setAttribute("id", "Set1");
    });
}
```

Comment: That's cool Derek.  Two answers in one day!  Working hard for rating boosts?

Comment: +1. I didn't even know something called `document.querySelectorAll()` existed in pure JavaScript LOL. I use jQuery all the time and I have forgotten a lot of the pure JavaScript stuff.

Comment: @Nathan - It is very convenience, but... as always, IE 6 and 7 don't support it... which is kind of annonying.

Comment: @Derek Do you mean the `document.querySelectorAll()` isn't supported in IE 6 and 7? That sucks, I wish IE was more like Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

Comment: @Nathan - Look at the bright side. IE 8 does support `.querySelectorAll()`, which definitely is cool!

Comment: IE 8 has querySelectorAll only in standards mode. In quirksmode it's missing.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), here's a code that changes the id of `#Set1` to `#Set2` when the mouse is moved over `.tomouseover` and changes back to `#Set1` when you mouse out:

```
$('.tomouseover').mouseover(function() {
    $('#Set1').attr('id','Set2');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('#Set2').attr('id','Set1');
});​
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/XNu5H/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you get that to JavaScript :D

Comment: @wagtail - See my answer if it is what you wanted.

Comment: @Derek I wasn't fast enough haha, I was converting mine to pure JavaScript but I'm not that good in it :P

Comment: @Nathan - I put your name in the answer, since the code is converted from yours. ;)